# Error when running db:pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm having problems when running `heroku db:pull -a my-app`. I get this message:

```
!    Heroku client internal error.
!    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
!    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       constant URI::WFKV_ not defined (NameError)
Backtrace:   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53:in `remove_const'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53:in `<module:URI>'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:12:in `require'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/multipart.rb:2:in `require'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/multipart.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:2:in `require'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:8:in `require'
             /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cg/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:207:in `require'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:207:in `load_taps'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:49:in `pull'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku db:pull -a my-app
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.33.2 (i486-linux) ruby/1.9.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was having the same issue.  Seems that db:pull is deprecated.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups